# Can't avoid overwriting everything on a text file

Tags: java

I posted a couple days ago about a project for my school that I was doing and I got some very useful help that allowed me to further my project. Despite this, something else has arisen. In this program that I am doing, I am meant to input different "training methods" for horses. This is input by the user in the program and is meant to write that training method into a text file. This works fine, however let's say I want to input another training method for a different horse. This will happen, but the input from the first horse will be completely deleted and only the last thing that was written to the text file will remain. Does anyone know why this could be and what are some steps I could do to fix it? Thank you! (Sorry for the long code I just legitimately do not know which part it is that could be messing up my program)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public AddNutrition() {
    initComponents();




    NutritionCB.removeAllItems();
    NutritionCB.addItem("Choose Horse...");

    try{
        FileReader horseReader = new FileReader("HorseFile.txt");
        BufferedReader horseBuffer = new BufferedReader(horseReader);
        String record = "";
        while((record = horseBuffer.readLine())!=null)
        {
            StringTokenizer tokenizerHorse = new StringTokenizer(record,",");
            String vHorseID = tokenizerHorse.nextToken();
            String vHorseName = tokenizerHorse.nextToken();
            String vHorseBreed = tokenizerHorse.nextToken();
            String vHorseDOB = tokenizerHorse.nextToken();
            String vHorseHeight = tokenizerHorse.nextToken();
            String vHorseHandSize = tokenizerHorse.nextToken();

            NutritionCB.addItem(vHorseBreed + "_" + vHorseName);
        }
        horseBuffer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception Error) {
        System.out.println("Error in reading file.");
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    NutritionCB = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    HorseID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    HorseName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    HorseBreed = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    HorseDOB = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    HorseHeight = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    HorseHandSize = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FoodName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    FoodQuantity = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    FoodTime = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    LoadButton = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Add Horse Nutrition");

    jLabel2.setText("Select Horse:");

    jLabel3.setText("Horse ID");

    jLabel4.setText("Horse Name");

    jLabel5.setText("Horse Breed");

    jLabel6.setText("Horse DOB");

    jLabel7.setText("Horse Height");

    jLabel8.setText("Horse Handsize");

    HorseID.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            HorseIDActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel9.setText("Food Name:");

    jLabel10.setText("Food Quantity:");

    jLabel11.setText("Food Time:");

    FoodName.setToolTipText("");
    FoodName.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            FoodNameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    LoadButton.setText("Load Horse");
    LoadButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            LoadButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setText("Save");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(213, 213, 213))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6))
                                    .addGap(28, 28, 28))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                    .addGap(46, 46, 46))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(HorseBreed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 105, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(HorseDOB)
                                .addComponent(HorseHandSize)
                                .addComponent(HorseHeight)
                                .addComponent(HorseName)
                                .addComponent(HorseID))
                            .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel11)
                                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                .addComponent(jLabel9))
                            .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(FoodQuantity, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 118, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(FoodTime)
                                .addComponent(FoodName)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                            .addComponent(NutritionCB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(LoadButton))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(278, 278, 278)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(128, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addComponent(FoodName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel10)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                            .addComponent(FoodQuantity, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel11)
                        .addComponent(FoodTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(NutritionCB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(LoadButton))
                    .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(HorseID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(HorseName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(HorseBreed, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(HorseDOB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(HorseHeight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(HorseHandSize, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8))))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(21, 21, 21))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void HorseIDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void FoodNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void LoadButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
String CBHorseLoading = NutritionCB.getSelectedItem()+"";
StringTokenizer stCBHorseLoad = new StringTokenizer(CBHorseLoading,"_");
String HCBBreed = stCBHorseLoad.nextToken().trim();
String HCBHorse = stCBHorseLoad.nextToken().trim();

try {
    FileReader horseReader = new FileReader("HorseFile.txt");
    BufferedReader horseBuffer = new BufferedReader(horseReader);
    String record = "";
    while((record = horseBuffer.readLine())!=null)
    {
        StringTokenizer TokenizerHorse = new StringTokenizer(record,",");
        String vHorseID = TokenizerHorse.nextToken();
        String vHorseName = TokenizerHorse.nextToken();
        String vHorseBreed = TokenizerHorse.nextToken();
        String vHorseDOB = TokenizerHorse.nextToken();
        String vHorseHeight = TokenizerHorse.nextToken();
        String vHorseHandSize = TokenizerHorse.nextToken();
        if (HCBHorse.equals(vHorseName)){
            System.out.println();

            HorseID.setText(vHorseID);
            HorseName.setText(vHorseName);
            HorseBreed.setText(vHorseBreed);
            HorseDOB.setText(vHorseDOB);
            HorseHeight.setText(vHorseHeight);
            HorseHandSize.setText(vHorseHandSize);


        }

    }
    horseBuffer.close();
}
catch(Exception Error){
    System.out.println("Error in loading horse.");
}


    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
boolean entryError = false; 
if(FoodName.getText().equals(""))
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the Horse Food            Name.","Error.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
 entryError = true; 

}
if(FoodQuantity.getText().equals("")&& entryError==false)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the Horse Food      Quantity.","Error.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
entryError = true; 

}
if(FoodTime.getText().equals("")&& entryError == false)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter the Horse Food     Times.","Error.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
entryError = true; 

}

if(entryError == false)
{


try {
    FileWriter tWriter = new FileWriter("HorseNutrition.txt");
    PrintWriter tPrinter = new PrintWriter(tWriter);

    tPrinter.println(HorseID.getText() + "," + FoodName.getText() + "," + FoodQuantity.getText() + "," + FoodTime.getText());
    tPrinter.close(); 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nutritional data has been saved.","Info",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 


}
catch(Exception error) {
    System.out.println("Error in saving nutritional data");
}
   }


}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField FoodName;
private javax.swing.JTextField FoodQuantity;
private javax.swing.JTextField FoodTime;
private javax.swing.JTextField HorseBreed;
private javax.swing.JTextField HorseDOB;
private javax.swing.JTextField HorseHandSize;
private javax.swing.JTextField HorseHeight;
private javax.swing.JTextField HorseID;
private javax.swing.JTextField HorseName;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton LoadButton;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> NutritionCB;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Look into "appending" or adding onto the end of a file. Also you are unlikely to get an answer by posting so much code, perhaps post only the code which writes to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method:

First, change

```
FileWriter tWriter = new FileWriter("HorseNutrition.txt");
```

to

```
OutputStreamWriter tWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("HorseNutrition.txt"));
```

`FileWriter` is just implemented to serve as abbreviation, so there's no logical difference here. In fact the `FileWriter(String)` constructor is doing pretty much what's stated below.

Then make use of the `FileOutputStream(File, boolean)` constructor. Here, the passed `boolean` denotes whether the data already contained in the file shall be remained, hence if the given input shall be appended.

This results in

```
OutputStreamWriter tWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("HorseNutrition.txt", true));
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if you only want to read or add horses. If you want to modify the data, this won't help.

Comment: @Kayaman You're perfectly right. However, OP stated 'I want to input another training method for a different horse', so I think it's fine.

Comment: I just added that as a caveat, since it's likely that horse editing functionality might appear too.